# Sampling intercept and slope pairs from lm in R

Tags: r, ancova

Let's say I have a model Y~X+trt, and by running lm and summary functions in R I get these results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X + trt)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.31706 -0.70884  0.09831  0.60996  2.46301 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 8.5782     0.6412  13.379  < 2e-16 ***
X                           2.1056     0.1542  13.658  < 2e-16 ***
trtB                       -1.8097     0.8234  -2.198 0.030597 *  
trtC                       -3.3090     0.6395  -5.174 1.42e-06 ***
trtE                       -3.5157     0.5844  -6.016 4.00e-08 ***
trtF                       -2.2839     0.6647  -3.436 0.000904 ***
trtG                       -3.0587     0.6263  -4.883 4.63e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9805 on 88 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8232,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8112 
F-statistic: 68.31 on 6 and 88 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I suspect that the slope estimates and the intercept estimates are not independent, co-varing with one another. The question is what do I have to do in order to sampling intercept and slope pairs for each treatment group, such that they conform the model?

Any helps would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you precise what kind of "conforming with the model" do you expect ? Maybe the R function `simulate` performs what you are looking for (see `?simulate`).

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneLaurent. What I meant by that is something along this line. Say for group A, if I were to (and I have tried this) randomly pair the slope ~ N(2.1056,0.1542), and the intercept ~ N(8.5782,0.6412), the simulated equations won't always stay within the estimated confidence bound given by the model. This is what I meant by not conforming the model. I just want to sample slopes and intercepts such that the simulated equations always stay within the confidence bound given by the model. Cheers

Comment: @Pakorn Welcome to the site! I think you may have a misunderstanding of what a confidence bound is. The confidence bound is generally a confidence bound on the expected value. A 95% confidence bound on the mean does not tell you that approximately 95% of your single observations will be within the confidence bound.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat Thank you for your comment and the answer below. They are both extremely helpful. Actually, indeed as you said, the confidence bound of the 'expected value' isn't the same as (much smaller than) the confidence bound of the 'data'. So if you don't mind. May I ask you, how to simulate the equations from the model so that they capture the confidence interval of the data, instead of the expected values? (I try to follow your comment below. It indeed under estimated the confidence bound of the data.) Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(mvtnrom) #needed for rmvnorm function

model=lm(y~x)
sigma.sq=vcov(model)
mu=model$coef

rmvnorm(n,mean=mu,sigma=sigma.sq)
```

This will simulate n values from the multivariate normal sampling distribution of your coefficient estimates. It will incorporate covariance between coefficients.

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much, sir (+1)

Comment: +1, the same code should work w/ a factor included. You may want to add `trt` to the `lm()` call to make the parallel easier for the OP to see.

Comment: @Pakorn, unfortunately, you can't upvote until your reputation is 15. If this has resolved your question, you can *accept* it by clicking the check mark to its left below the vote total.